# Elementary set theory proof by contradiction

Tags: inequality, polynomials

Let $A = \{x \in \Bbb{R} : |2x -1| \leq 5\}$, let $B =  \{x \in \Bbb{R} : |2x - 1| < 3\}$, let $D =\{x \in \Bbb{R} : x^2(7-x^2) \geq 7\}$ and let $E = \{x \in \Bbb{R} : 2x(x-2)(x+2) \geq 5 \}$. Prove by contradiction that $(A - B) \subseteq (D \cup E)$

I tried doing this in a sort of direct way but the problem got a little to complicated since it was hard to solve for $2x(x-2)(x+2) \geq 5$. I can't see any easy and elegant way to do it. I've also shown that $(A - B) = [-2, -1]\cup[2, 3]$. From there I tried to show how these two separate sets fit into D or E but I don't know if this is the proper way to solve this by contradiction.

Comment: It might be enough to give a counterexpample, but I am not sure if this counts as 'contradiction' but it might be.

Comment: The definitions of $\;D,\,E\;$ are pretty messy to sort out the real numbers that belong to them, but using the hint in the answer below perhaps you can take some particular cases and show a contradiction.

Comment: @Cornman What kind of counterexample could you give?

Comment: @DonAntonio I don't see how I can get the contradiction from that, isn't that just the same problem?

Comment: @Cornman how does this show $(A - B) \subseteq D \cup E$ ?

Comment: Hi, @Cornman could you please clarify on this? I'm still stuck on trying to prove this. Don't see how to do it without finding the zeroes of the functions of sets $D$ and $E$.

Comment: @EtherealMist I made a mistake, so I deleted my comments on it. Sorry.

Comment: @DonAntonio could you clarify? I am having trouble finding the answer using the hint

Comment: @EtherealMist Either whoever thought of this problem has a very specific goal to make you students work out things with high degree polynomial equations, or else he just made a mistake, or he's just a sadist...or else I'm missing some rather tricky way to solve this apparently awfully ugly and horrible-looking problem. The matter to classify the elements in $\;D\;$ is already ugly enough, but if you add to this the problem to classify the elements in E then this becomes a truly monstruous exercise...Sorry, I've nothing more than what you've already done.

Comment: @DonAntonio yeah I know, I solved for the zeroes in D and to solve for the zeroes in E is definitely beyond the scope of this course since it involves numerical approximations and this is a first year intro to proofs course lol

Comment: @EtherealMist Then it is probably a mistake...are you sure you copied correctly the sets $\;A,B,D,E\;$ ?

Comment: How about solving it geometrically? Draw $2x(x-2)(x+2)$ and see when it is above $5$

Comment: @FareedAF I thought about this too and actually tried to do it this way but it seemed too imprecise but honestly it's the only plausible way I can see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose to the contrary that the inclusion does not hold. Then there exists a point $x_0\in (A - B)\setminus (D \cup E)$. We already know that  $A - B =[-2, -1]\cup[2, 3]$. Define functions $d$ and $e$ on $\Bbb R$ by putting $d(x)=x^2(7-x^2)-7$ and $e(x)=2x(x-2)(x+2)-5$ for each $x\in\Bbb R$. It is easy to check that $x\in D$ iff $d(x)\ge 0$ iff $\left|x^2-\tfrac 72\right|\le \tfrac{\sqrt{21}}{2}$. Since $\tfrac{\sqrt{21}}{2}\ge \tfrac 94$, we see that if $|x_0|\in \left[\tfrac{\sqrt{5}}2, \tfrac{\sqrt{23}}2 \right]$ then $x_0\in D$, a contradiction. If $x_0\ge \tfrac{\sqrt{23}}2$ then $e(x_0)\ge e\left(\tfrac{\sqrt{23}}2\right)= \tfrac{7\sqrt{23}}4-5>0$, so $x_0\in E$, a contradiction.  If $-\tfrac{\sqrt{5}}2\le x_0\le -1$ then $e(x_0)\ge 2\left(4-\tfrac 54\right)-5>0$, so $x_0\in E$, a contradiction.

Comment: Thank you for the help. Just a few questions though, where did you get $|x^2 - \frac{7}{2}| \leq \frac{\sqrt{21}}{2}$? Also, why does $\frac{\sqrt{21}}{2} \geq \frac{9}{4}$ imply that $|x_0| \in \Bigl[\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}, \frac{\sqrt{23}}{2}\Bigr]$? Thanks again.

Comment: Just looked at my notes. Assuming you got $|x^2 - \frac{7}{2}| \leq \frac{\sqrt{21}}{2}$ by finding the zeros of $d(x)$ which is what I did as well.

Comment: @EtherealMist $d(x)\ge 0$ iff $-x^4+7x^2-7\ge 0$ iff $\left(x^2-\tfrac 72\right)^2-\tfrac {49}{4}+7\ge 0$ iff $\left|x^2-\tfrac 72\right|\le \sqrt{\tfrac{49-28}{4}}$. Since $\tfrac{\sqrt{21}}{2}\ge \tfrac 94$, if $\left|x^2-\tfrac 72\right|\le \tfrac 94$ (that is if $|x|\in \left[\tfrac{\sqrt{5}}2, \tfrac{\sqrt{23}}2 \right]$) then $\left|x^2-\tfrac 72\right|\le \tfrac{\sqrt{21}}{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

Assume $(A - B) \subseteq (D \cup E)$
is false.  Thus
exists x in A that is not in $D \cup E \cup B.$
Show such an x is not possible.

Comment: Isn't this just the same problem or am I missing something here? Since you want to show $\exists x \in A$ such that $x \notin D \cup E \cup B$ is a contradiction and the middle part of $A$ ($ -1 < x < 2$) is already in $B$, then aren't you again trying to show $[-2, -1] \cup [2, 3] \in D \cup E$? Any more help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: could you clarify?